# Cannot set the reference to the user document in courses mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I am currently working on a RESTful API, and I am trying to reference the users schema in the courses document such that, when a POST request gets sent to the route of the course, a course is created in the DB and has as one of its fields a reference to the user that created it. However, for the life of me, I cannot figure out why the "user" field is not appearing when I post. There seem to be quite a few of these questions here on Stack so I may just be adding to the pile, but I tried their solutions and they did not work for me

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')

var Schema = mongoose.Schema


var userSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }, 
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }, 
    emailAddress: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },  
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    } 
});

var CourseSchema = new Schema({
    user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}, //FOR some reason this is not showing up on any courses created using the 
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    estimatedTime: {
        type: String
    },
    materialsNeeded: {
        type: String
    }
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
var Course = mongoose.model('Course', CourseSchema);

module.exports = {Course, User};
```

Do you see anything in here that would preclude the user field from appearing when a new course is created?

I have attached some screenshots to further explain.

[image]
This first image is a screen of the currently authenticated user credentials (fake data obviously). This is the user that is sending the POST request for the new course. I would expect his information to be attached to the course (see screenshot 3)

[image]
This image shows the body of the request that is sent. You can see that the key-value pairs match what is in the CourseSchema. I would expect that the "user" field would be created once the POST request is sent.

[image]
This last image is some dummy data that is the expected result.

Thanks all for taking a look at this!

Answer (score 0):

User field will not be automatically added to the course document. You have to manually set the user field in the request body itself or while creating a course.
Example of the course body to be sent:-

```
{
 user: "userId", 
 title: "test",
 description: "test",
 estimatedTime: "test",
 materialsNeeded: 1
}
```

Also, the result of this will not include the whole user document as you have mentioned in the expected result. It will only return the userId. However, while accessing the course you can populate the user field to get the whole user document. Example for the same

```
Course.find({...query}).populate("user")
```